# What does it mean for something to hold in a particular topology?

Tags: general-topology

Some of the exercises in topology take the form "Does [insert property here] hold in the [topology 1], [topology 2], etc.?" I'm wondering what this means at the theoretical level. I've seen strategies using the basis elements of a particular topology as well as if the topology is induced by a metric, but I'm unclear as to what would determine when a particular strategy should be used or how it relates a high-level understanding of something holding in a particular topology.

Comment: Your question title and question body aren't really the same question. Which of those more accurately captures your problem?

Comment: It seems a table of strategies and heuristics on when to use them would be of most value to you.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas So I think the combined question would be what-theoretically-does something holding in a particular topology mean? And then, are there any specific strategies for determining this given that theoretical understanding?

Comment: These exercises are probably just to get more familiarity with examples, and what can go wrong whit this or that topology. In the topological world you either have two cases. In the first case you just work with general topological spaces, on an abstract level, so you do not really have to care what the topology really is, but mostly that you have a topological space after all. The second case is that you have a specific space, say $\mathbb{R}$. Most spaces come with a certain topology. The standard topology. In the case of $\mathbb{R}$ this is the topology induced by the absolute value.

Comment: These "standard topologies" normally are the most natural choice, and the most interesting choice, as you normally have a so called "universal property".

Comment: In Topology you kind off do not care what the topology is. You care about the continuous functions between spaces. In the same sense as you do not care about vector spaces in linear algebra, but the linear maps. So it might be misleading when you first study topology. The subject is not about proving that a certain family of sets is a topology or stuff like that, as these questions are not so important or interesting to answer. As I said, normally  when you work with a specfic space, you also have a concrete topology, and those exercises just give more examples, and oppertunity to practice.

Comment: @Cornman That makes sense-one of the exercises was on the differences between the uniform and box topologies and I was somewhat confused as to the overall importance of learning these differences.

Comment: You might benefit from the book "Counterexamples in Topology" (ISBN: 978-0486687353 for the 1995 version).  This book gives many examples of constructions and properties that hold in one topology and not another (on the same set of points).  There's much more there as well (relations among kinds of compactness, relations among separability axioms, et al.).